# 安定なソートかどうかの判定方法について

Tags: sort

[AOJ 安定なソート](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/commentary.jsp?id=ALDS1_2_C&pattern=post&type=general&filter=Algorithm)に関しての質問です。

```
1 isStable(in, out)
2   for i = 0 to N-1
3     for j = i+1 to N-1
4       for a = 0 to N-1
5         for b = a+1 to N-1
6           if in[i] と in[j] の数字が等しい && in[i] == out[b] && in[j] == out[a]
7             return false
8 return true
```

が擬似コードとして示されておりますが、in[i] == out[b] && in[j] == out[a]の部分のaとbがなぜ必要なのか、この部分があることによりなぜ判定ができるのかが、考えてもわかりませんでした。

この理由について教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2番目の変数`j`についてのループが`i+1`から始まっていることに注目します。これは「`i`よりも右にある（後にある）要素について調べていく」ということです。`a`と`b`についても同様に、`b`には`a`よりも右にある要素が入ります。言い換えれば、`i < j` かつ `a < b` が常に成り立ちます。

そして、`in[i] == out[b]` は「入力された`i`番目の要素がソート結果の`b`番目にあること」、`in[j] == out[a]` は「入力された`j`番目の要素がソート結果の`a`番目にあること」を示しています。ここで、`a < b` なので、`i`番目の要素は`j`番目の要素より右に動いたことになります。

ところが、これは安定なソートの定義に矛盾します。安定なソートでは、要素の値が同じときの前後関係（〜が〜よりも右にくる）が維持されるのでした。したがって、この場合ソートは安定でないといえます。

---

また、疑似コードは以下のようにも書き換えられます（ループを分けました）。

```
isStable(in, out)
 for i = 0 to N-1
   for j = i+1 to N-1
     if in[i] と in[j] の数字が等しい
       for a = 0 to N-1
         for b = a+1 to N-1
           if in[i] == out[b] && in[j] == out[a]
             return false
 return true
```

Comment: "=="がアドレスの比較というのは誤りです。設問は、比較対象のデータが"S8"とか"H4"で、含まれる数字を元にソートするという設定です。なので、「数字が等しい」と「文字列が等しい(==)」が別の表記でかかれています。

Comment: @suzukis 指摘ありがとうございます。該当部分を削除しました。